# UISearchBar as header UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

How can I make `UISearchBar` hide when scroll `UItableview` up and show when scroll down, like the GLIDE - VIDEO TEXT iPhone application does?

Comment: Add Searchbar in section.

Comment: @user3828270 If you can reply to this comment with a link to an external picture I will add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UISearchBar *temp = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
temp.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
temp.showsCancelButton=NO;
temp.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
temp.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
temp.delegate=self;
YourTable.tableHeaderView=temp;
```

finally YourTableView add to ScrollView.

```
[yourScrollView addSubView:YourTableView];
```

May be it's help to you

Comment: It does work as my expected. I want UISearchBar is always on UITableView top, but it doesn't scrolled down when scrolling table down. But it will hide ( under UINavigationBar) when scrolling up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the UISearchBar as the header of UITableView. It works even if the rows are with sections(like in Glide) or not.

Hope it helps.